# Summing some datum for requests in each domain that fall in a date range

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have a LINQ query which works fine. I am however very interested to understand if this can be written in a more optimum way...

```
var query = (from r in Results.All.AsEnumerable()
                       where r.RequestType.Id == Id &&
                             r.DateFrom >= sDate &&
                             r.DateTo <= eDate
                       group r by new {r.Data_1} into g
                       select new {data = g.Key.Data_1, 
                                    sum = g.Sum(s => int.Parse(s.Data_2))}).ToList();
```

I am trying to sum Data_2 (stored as a string) by a unique list of Data_1 all by a given date range.

I have provided some sample data below:

[image: table data for query]

For example: facebook.com = 51, m.facebook.com = 94 etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a case where a `foreach` loop might work better.  Your LINQ query iterates for your data several times.  Where as a `foreach` loop and a dictionary, should be able to accomplish this in one loop.  Something like this:

```
Dictionary<string,int> query = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach(var r in Results)
{
    if(r.RequestType.Id == Id && r.DateFrom >= sDate && r.DateTo <= eDate)
    {
         if(query.ContainsKey(r.Data_1))
         {
             query[r.Data_1] += int.Parse(r.Data_2);
         }
         else
         {
             query.Add(r.Data_1, int.Parse(r.Data_2));
         }
    }
}
```

While there is a Dictionary lookup for each item it should be more than offset by calculating the sum on the fly rather than at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @tinstaafl's answer, sometimes a plain `foreach` loop makes more efficient code.

Just a note about readability / maintainability, perhaps for cases where a LINQ query does work better: `Data_1` and `Data_2` make very poor names to work with; unless you know what the data looks like, the code itself doesn't help understanding the data, and I find that's a missed opportunity.

Consider naming anonymous types' members, whoever is maintaining the code (future you?) will be grateful!

```
var query = (from r in Results.All.AsEnumerable()
                   where r.RequestType.Id == Id &&
                         r.DateFrom >= sDate &&
                         r.DateTo <= eDate
                   group r by new {Url = r.Data_1} into g
                   select new {Url = g.Key.Url, 
                                Referrals = g.Sum(s => int.Parse(s.Data_2))}).ToList();
```

And now you have a list of anonymous types with `Url` and `Referrals` members (assuming the meaning of `Data_2` here).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I am particularly impressed that you knew these were referrals :-)

Comment: @Webb looking at this answer again, I'm actually impressed it was posted from my phone! :)

Comment: ha - That's insane!!! High five

Answer (score 1):

The Enumerable.GroupBy has a way to do this in a single grouping criteria...

```
Results.All.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.RequestType.Id == Id
        && r.DateFrom >= sDate
        && r.DateTo <= sDate)
    .GroupBy(t => t.Data_1, (key,set) => new { data = key, sum = set.Sum(s=>int.Parse(s.Data_2)) });
```

I'm not sure if there's a way to express this in the fluent syntax or not